# How to use caching_sha2_password and mysql_native_password plugin for same user?

Tags: mysql

How to use caching_sha2_password and mysql_native_password plugin for same user in MYSQL 8.0.28

Example:

```
dev_customers_rw    | %           | caching_sha2_password
dev_customers_rw    | %           | mysql_native_password
```

Because go language need caching_sha2_password plugin and Django need mysql_native_password  plugin method.

How to achieve both the plugin for same single user ?
Please any one help me here.

Comment: How do you create the hashed passwords? In MYSQL or in the respective Apps

Comment: I don't think the same user can have two different auth methods. You should create a second user with the same privileges for your Django app to use.

Comment: You can also build your own MySQL-Python connector that supports caching_sha2_password: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/04/18/mysql-python-adding-caching_sha2_password-tlsv1-2-support/